# Drools - Understanding this example with drl file stored in a different location than the Kbase name attribute of the kmodule file

Tags: drools, rule-engine, business-rules

I was looking at this example with the KieBase defined as follows:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <kmodule
        xmlns="http://jboss.org/kie/6.0.0/kmodule">
    <kbase name="kbase1">
        <ksession name="ksession1"/>
    </kbase>
 </kmodule>
```

I was expecting the drl file to be in src/main/resources/kbase1.  I made this assumption because reading the book Mastering JBoss Drools 6, it was indicated that the kbase name is where the drl file  should be placed. The sentence reads below:

'Notice that the name attribute of the KieBase is the same as the directory structure that we are using under /src/test/resources/ directory, where the rules are stored. '

However, in the example, the drl file in placed in the following directory:
src/main/resources/namedkiesession.

Here is the file: HAL1.drl

```
  package org.drools.example.api.namedkiesession

   import org.drools.example.api.namedkiesession.Message

   global java.io.PrintStream out

   rule "rule 1" salience 10 when
    m : Message( )
   then
     out.println( m.getName() + ": " +  m.getText() );
   end

  rule "rule 2" when
     Message( text == "Hello, HAL. Do you read me, HAL?" )
  then
    insert( new Message("HAL", "Dave. I read you." ) );
  end
```

How does this work if the KieBase name is not where the actual drl file is stored?  The full source code is here:

https://github.com/kiegroup/drools/blob/6.0.x/drools-examples-api/pom.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have just found an error (or typo) in the book. The `name` of a `KieBase` is an arbitrary name you choose and has no relation with the directory structure where the .drl files are located.

The attribute of a `<kbase>` element that you can use to tell what packages (directories) to include is the `packages` attribute and not the `name` attribute If the `packages` attribute is not specified, then the `KieBase` will include any artifact (drl, bpmn, dtable, etc.) that is located under the `resource` directory.

You can find a better explanation of the attributes of a `<kbase>` in [the official Drools' documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.5.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html) (look for table 4.1).

Note that starting from version 7.18, the semantics of the `packages` attributes suffered a slight (but fundamental) change as stated in the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.24.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#_groupdrlsinkiebasesbyfolderoption).

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thank you, I do appreciate this. One thing I have observed though is I've seen many examples where the folder is the same as the name attribute.